# Delete a Sidekiq job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

When i add a product inside my cart, in my case the cart is also the order/index, it starts a job to delete the order if it hasn't been paid within 10 minutes from his creation and revert the status of the products from not available to available.

At the moment it creates a job everytime i add a new product to the cart basically

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:create, :update]
  before_action :set_order, only: [:payorder, :index, :destroy, :update, :product_ordinable, :show]
  before_action :product_ordinable, only: [:destroy]

  def payorder
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      source: params[:stripeToken],
      email:  params[:stripeEmail]
      )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      customer:     customer.id,
      amount:       @order.amount_cents,
      description:  "Payment for your products for order #{@order.id}",
      currency:     @order.amount.currency
      )

    @order.update(payment: charge.to_json, paid: true)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_path, notice: 'Payment Completed!' }
    end

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:alert] = e.message
    render :index
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  delegate *%w(
  unpaid_orders?
  orders
  ), to: :current_user

  def create
    if @product.ordinable?
      order = unpaid_orders? ? orders.last : orders.create!
      @product.update(ordinable: false)
      if order.products << @product
        order.update(amount: order.products.sum(&:price))
        @notice = 'Product added to the Cart!'
        OrderPaidCheckJob.set(wait: 10.minutes).perform_later(order.id)
        # unless unpaid_orders
      else
        @notice = 'There was a problem while adding the product to the cart!'
      end
    else
      @notice = 'There was a problem while adding the product to the cart!'
    end
    redirect_to products_path, notice: @notice
  end

  def update
    @order.products.delete(Product.find(@product.id))
    @product.update(ordinable: true)
    if @order.products.empty?
      @order.destroy
      @notice = 'Order deleted!'
    else
      @order.update(amount: @order.products.sum(&:price))
      @notice = 'Order Updated!'
    end
    redirect_to orders_path, notice: @notice
  end

  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'The order was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_order
    @order = current_user.orders.last
  end

  def product_ordinable
    @order.products.each do |x|
      x.ordinable = true
      x.save
    end
  end

  def previous_orders
  end
end
```

```
class OrderPaidCheckJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(order_id)
    order = Order.find(order_id)
    if order.paid == false
      order.products.each do |x|
        x.ordinable = true
        x.save
      end
      order.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to delete that job and or start it over when i add another product in my cart to not see the order deleted automatically after 10 minutes while shopping.

Comment: how about just check the order last active time(updated_at) from inside the sidekick job. if it's less than 10min you can end the job.

Comment: you should use a state machine on the cart and if the cart is 'active' again, the job terminates early.

Comment: @Oshanz your solution is very simple and smart. If i can't find a solution using Sidekiq i'll go with that :)

Comment: @Anthony i'd like to know how to implement it really..

Comment: @LuisCarlosQuarta I add it to the below, you can mark if it was useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class OrderPaidCheckJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(order_id)
    order = Order.find(order_id)
    return if order.nil? || order.paid
    if order.updated_at > 10.minutes.ago # order recently changed
      OrderPaidCheckJob.set(wait: 10.minutes).perform_later(order.id)
      return # end this job. check again 10min later
    end
    order.products.each do |x|
      x.ordinable = true
      x.save
    end
    order.destroy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unique job, this is one of the many features that Sidekiq Enterprise has.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Unique-Jobs